# StaticPortMappingCollection is null

Tags: c#, portforwarding

my StaticPortMappingCollection is remaining null. I am trying to do port forwarding application. Below is my code:

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
int port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);
mappings.Add(port, "TCP", port, lblLocalIP.Text, true, this.Name);
```

Comment: Title is the answer.your `StaticPortMappingCollection` is null.what is returning from `new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass()` ? did you initialize your collection ? Is it `auto-implemented` property ? Where is the constructor code ? How can we know why `upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection` is null?

Comment: you cannot instantiate NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection it is read only

Comment: It turned out that the router did not had UPNP enabled. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: Not even the first time this is asked. [Can't add a static port mapping in my c# application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856559/cant-add-a-static-port-mapping-in-my-c-sharp-application)