# NATUPnP VB.NET constantly throwing errors

Tags: vb.net, nat, upnp

NATUPnP refuses to add mapping.

```
Dim upnpnat As UPnPNATClass = New UPnPNATClass
Dim mappingz As IStaticPortMappingCollection = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection
mappingz.Add(200, "UDP", 200, "192.168.1.70", True, "BlockHavenClient")
```

It only throws the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have tracked the problem to this line:

```
mappingz.Add(200, "UDP", 200, "192.168.1.70", True, "BlockHavenClient")
```

Really stuck on this problem, please help!

**EDIT**

My router does support UPnP, and it is enabled, even with the firewall off, that is not the problem.

Comment: Check the comments in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262410/staticportmappingcollection-is-null

Comment: I hope you can fix it but there are also .Net libraries to map ports using UPnp. Try Open.NAT (https://github.com/lontivero/Open.Nat) or Mono.Nat (https://github.com/mono/Mono.Nat)