# NATUPNPLib IStaticPortMappingCollection is null

Tags: c#, portforwarding, nat, upnp

I am trying to use the NATUPNPLib using C# to quickly port-forward. Here's my very simple code.

```
UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new UPnPNATClass();
IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
```

After the last line 'mappings' is always null.

I've read up on the issue ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856559/cant-add-a-static-port-mapping-in-my-c-sharp-application)), but none of the answeres are correct/apply in this case. I am aware, that UPnP needs to be enabled on the router (which it is), the same with the network discovery in the windows control panel, and I'm running the application as an administrator.

How do I fix this?

Comment: pc firewall enabled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add a static port mapping in my c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856559/cant-add-a-static-port-mapping-in-my-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Disabling firewall makes no difference